# Including a classpath entry for source

Tags: gwt

My first GWT program is not running and showing error as shown below. Plz help. I don't understand what went wrong :( This is what it is shown in the console.

```
Loading modules
   com.BasicProject.basic
      Loading inherited module 'com.BasicProject.basic'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/BasicProject/basic.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Comment: Can you show the content of your `.gwt.xml` file?

Answer (score 5):

Your `<PROJECT>.gwt.xml` file has a invalid `<inherits.../>` line.

If you are trying to inherit some module, you have have to pass the path of that module's `gwt.xml` file.

I'm **guessing** your module has this structure:

```
src
    - com.BasicProject.basic
        - client
        - server
        - shared
        - Basic.gwt.xml
```

your `<inherits.../>` line should say this:

`<inherits name='com.BasicProject.basic.Basic'/>`

because you have to inherit `Basic.gwt.xml`.

See the **Loading Modules** section of this article for more details: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml

Comment: My module structure is:


src
  -com.BasicProject
      -basicProject.gwt.xml
  -com.BasicProject.client
      -BasicProject.java


and the contents of basicProject.gwt.xml is

<module>
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
 <source path="client" />
 <entry-point class="com.BasicProject.client.BasicProject" />
</module>

Does amything need to be changed??

Comment: Yippe I solved the problem. Actually in the arguments under Run Configurations the arguments passed was com.BasicProject.basic instead of com.BasicProject.basicProject.........so eclipse was the culprit as it could not append the correct name by default. Anyways thanx for your concern Churro :)